# Splitting rails models vs. using one model for a combined form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am working on an application that allows various people from different departments in a company log in and edit a form.  Each department has specific fields in the form that only they are allowed to edit and view.

Would it be more organized code if I create one model for the entire set of fields and based on who logs in, render a different form containing the necessary fields?  Or would it be better to split the department-specific fields into their own models and then based on who logs in, render a form containing their specific fields and relate the records from different departments together through a foreign key of some sort?

Answer (score 2):

"It depends" is probably the best answer.
How many fields do you have? How much logic exists per department form type?

If you split all the fields to separate models (and corresponding tables) it will become a hassle if you ever want a full overview of the forms after they have been filled in, because they would be in separate tables. You'd have to go through every association of the form to get the full form.

If you still want to split them, because you have a lot of logic per department, you could point all your models to one 'main' table that contains all the fields, using [table_name](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/ActiveRecord/ModelSchema/ClassMethods/table_name). That way you have all the data in one table and you can easily retrieve it. However, you'd also have to save the type of form in order to retrieve it in the correct model, probably more trouble than it's worth. (If it's the best thing to save all your fields in one table depends as well, how often does it get retrieved or does it get inserted/updated more often.)

Simple forms will probably fit just fine in one model. Unless you have a lot of non-sharable code per department it probably isn't worth it to split the form into separate models. If you do split the form into models you probably should create one main form model and have the department models extend it for whatever bit of reusable form logic there is.

After all that, I would say, I prefer simplicity so I'd probably save it in one model.

Answer (score 0):

I'd split the fields and then you can setup your models with [accepts_nested_attributes_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) to build your form appropriately.